# How to create skill tree?

Tags: algorithm

I would like to create a skill tree for my own and a community usage. I have data in format like below:

```
skill_1 [description etc.] requires: none
skill_2 [...] requires: skill_1
skill_3 [...] requires: skill_1, skill_2
skill_4 [...] requires: skill_1 OR skill_2
```

(data format from Civilization 5 units promotion)

now i want to change those informations into graphic, tree-like structure. Something like: [skill tree image](http://nick.gladius.org/projects/planner/index.html)

The main problem I have is that connections between skills tangle and I would recive mess instead of clear, helpful picture, when I add those skills just one by one. Is there any (sort?) algorithm to prevent (or minimalise) crossing connections? Or I have to possition them mannually in a graphic program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an automatic graph layout program like [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org).

Comment: I checked that program, looks promising, thanks! I also checked theory - nothing trivial ;-).